Is it possible to add a "InputField" in ChoiceField in Django?
I'm in the process of developing a form that aligns with a database model. One of the fields in this form requires users to select from a range of options.
Initially, I implemented this using Django's ChoiceField. However, I'm exploring the possibility of allowing users to input their own option if it's not available in the predefined choices.
Is there a way to integrate this?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
